# os.getenv does not work under vs code + jupyter

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter

I can't get bellow simple 2 lines python code work uner my vscode with jupyter extension:

```
#%%
import os

print("key:" + str(os.getenv('TIINGO_KEY')))
```

it out put:
[image]

as I have added 'TIINGO_KEY' as enviroment variable under both of my fish and .bashrc

when I do it under my jupyter + Mac safari browser, or my fish terminal, the program out put exactly as expected like:

```
key:52c54923098
```

---update

very strange, it turns out some kind of relation with bellow lines

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas_datareader as pdr
```

after I restart my vs code, actually it just works, but then I add above 2 lines, it goes to some crash when I run second time:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to restart the Jupyter or select another kernel? It seems to have no problem with that two lines import codes.

Comment: yes, I did try restart my vs code several times, so evetually I found out my problem with the two lines 'unrelated codes'. after 'error:direct kernel connection broken' my os apis no longer work

Comment: after the error happen, even I remove the '2 lines unrelated code' my os.getenv won't be work

Comment: Have you tried to switch to another kernel?

Comment: Could you Go into your output panel Jupyter and copy the output & paste it?

Comment: Thanks Steven, for you keep on tracking, I was not able to re-produce the failure, since I get up today. I maybe keep it for a while and see if it happens again, I will let you know. regarding the 'output pannel', I can only see either nother or "Key:None", and the kernel was reporting at the bottom right corner as "direct kernel connection broken"